# Submit 2 form on link click Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, I am trying to submit 2 form on a link click code are below.

```js
$('#logout').click(function(){
    $('#logout-form').submit(doubleSubmit);
    function doubleSubmit(e1) {
        $('#logout-form1').submit();   
    };
});
```

Can any one suggest what is wrong with above code, and what will be correct code.

logout : id of the link
logout-form : Form one id
logout-form1 : Form two id

Thanks

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/skddel/tumwxrc1/1/

Comment: What should happen on link click and what is happening now?

Comment: at link click both form should be submit. For now first form is being submitted.

Comment: I tried above using that first form is being submitted only.

Comment: Think about whether you _actually_ need to submit two forms. Maybe send a single AJAX request instead?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to point to your jsfiddle? Most folks won't read the comments and simply skip your Q.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like to submit the 2 different forms by single button click.

```
$('#logout').click(function(){
 $("#logout-form").submit();
 $("#logout-form1").submit();
})
```

updated my js fiddle with ajax call [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/zxv0dur2/17/)

Comment: Ok, After form submission how we can redirect to the first form action . It's being redirected to the 2nd form action.

Comment: hi @skd i suggest u to use ajax requests for this, coz it will do the work your ask.